# Laravel - Using (:any?) wildcard for ALL routes?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, wildcard, laravel-3

I am having a bit of trouble with the routing.

I'm working on a CMS, and I need two primary routes. `/admin` and `/(:any)`. The `admin` controller is used for the route `/admin`, and the `view` controller should be used for anything else than `/admin`. From the `view` controller, I will then parse the url and show the correct content.

This is what I have:

```
Route::get(array('admin', 'admin/dashboard'), array('as' => 'admin', 'uses' =>'admin.dashboard@index'));
Route::any('(:any)', 'view@index');
```

The first route works, but the second one doesn't. I played around with it a little bit, and it seems if I use `(:any)` without the question mark, it only works if I put something after `/`. If i *do* put the question mark there, it doesn't work at all.

I want all of the following routes to go to view@index:

```
/
/something
/something/something
/something/something/something
/something/something/something/something
...etc...
```

Is this possible without hardcoding a bunch of `(:any?)/(:any?)/(:any?)/(:any?)` (which I don't even know works)?

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Edit: There has been some confusion since the release of Laravel 4 regarding this topic, this answer was targeting Laravel 3.

There are a few ways to approach this.

The first method is matching `(:any)/(:all?)`:

```
Route::any('(:any)/(:all?)', function($first, $rest=''){
    $page = $rest ? "{$first}/{$rest}" : $first;
    dd($page);
});
```

Not the best solution because it gets broken into multiple parameters, and for some reason (:all) doesn't work by itself (bug?)

The second solution is to use a regular expression, this is a better way then above in my opinion.

```
Route::any( '(.*)', function( $page ){
    dd($page);
});
```

There is one more method, which would let you check if there are cms pages even when the route may have matched other patterns, provided those routes returned a 404. This method modifies the event listener defined in `routes.php`:

```
Event::listen('404', function() {
    $page = URI::current();
    // custom logic, else
    return Response::error('404');
});
```

However, my preferred method is #2. I hope this helps. Whatever you do, make sure you define all your other routes above these catch all routes, any routes defined after will never trigger.

Comment: Awesome, just what i needed. The second method will probably work just fine, although method one is also tempting to use, because i will end up breaking the route up in sections by `/` anyways. Eg. if i want to view a subpage, i would go to `/parent/subpage`, so i would need to parse that from the `view` controller and display the correct page. I'm not sure which method is most appropriate for this kind of use, but i guess in the end it doesn't matter?

Comment: Can't get solution #2 to work :| I'm getting a Error: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

Comment: If you find that #2 doesn't work you may be using Laravel 4. In which case, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178426/get-all-routes-laravel-4) may help. Which boils down to `Route::any('{all}', function($page) { dd($page); })->where('all', '.*');`

Answer (score 136):

### Laravel 5

This solution works fine on Laravel 5:

```
Route::get('/admin', function () {

  // url /admin

});

Route::get('/{any}', function ($any) {

  // any other url, subfolders also

})->where('any', '.*');
```

---

### Lumen 5

This is for Lumen instead:

```
$app->get('/admin', function () use ($app) {
  //
});

$app->get('/{any:.*}', function ($any) use ($app) {
  //
});
```

Comment: Work for me! But what if I want to have more parameters after that. Example: $app->get('/admin/{select}/query/{query}', function () use ($app) {}->where('select', '.*')->->where('query', '.*');

Comment: @Francisco You can add your new rule between the rule `'/admin'` and the rule `'/{any:.*}'` or just replace the rule `'/admin'` with your new rule if you do not need the `'/admin'` url without parameters.

Comment: Came here for the lumen. Verified worked with Lumen 5.5. Thanks!

Answer (score 50):

Hitting a 404 status seems a bit wrong to me. This can get you in all kind of problems when logging the 404's. I recently bumped into the same wildcard routing problem in Laravel 4 and solved it with the following snippet:

```
Route::any('{slug}', function($slug)
{
    //do whatever you want with the slug
})->where('slug', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?');
```

This should solve your problem in a controlled way. The regular expression can be simplified to:

```
'(.*)?'
```

But you should use this at your own risk.

**Edit (addition):**

As this overwrites a lot of routes, you should consider wrapping it in an "App::before" statement:

```
    App::before(function($request) {
            //put your routes here
    });
```

This way, it will not overwrite custom routes you define later on.

Comment: Also worked for me. I put it after my other routes inside a route group to catch all incorrect api endpoints.

Comment: Yeah this is the approach I use, and it works in L4.1, however I prefer a single line like this: `Route::any('admin/{allsegments}', array('as'=>'admin', 'uses'=> 'AppBackend\Controllers\AdminController@index'))->where('allsegments','(.*)?');`

Answer (score 14):

```
Route::get("{path}", "SomeController@serve")->where('path', '.+');
```

The above code will capture the recursive sub urls you mentioned:

```
/
/something
/something/something
/something/something/something
/something/something/something/something
```

Any other special cases, such as admin/*, you can capture before this one.

Comment: this is same as `->where('path', '.*');`

Comment: This is working but we should some change as given    Route::get("/{path?}", "SomeController@serve")->where('path', '.+');

Answer (score 8):

Just spelling-out my experience in case it helps someone piece something together.

I built a self-API-consuming React app on Laravel.
It has a single view served by Laravel/Lumen.
It uses the React router.
**Clicking links in the app always worked, but typing-in URLs needed the following consideration:**

In Laravel I used the following in my web.php routes file:

```
Route::view('/{path?}', 'app')
    ->where('path', '.*')
    ->name('react');
```

And everything worked.

Then I switched the project to Lumen.
Thanks to this post, I used the following in my web.php routes file:

```
$router->get('/{all:.*}', function() {
    return view('app');
});
```

This worked for first level URLS such as:

```
/
/something
```

However,

```
/something/something etc.
```

did not.

I looked in the network tab in Google Developer tools and noticed that the URL for app.js was appending */something* in front of app.js on second and higher tier URLS, such as:

```
myapp.com/something
app.js URL:  myapp.com/js/app.js  (as it should be)

myapp.com/something/something
app.js URL:  myapp.com/something/js/app.js  (not found)
```

All I had to do was add a leading slash to my app.js source  in my single view page such as:

```
<script src="/js/app.js" defer></script>
```

Instead of:

```
<script src="js/app.js" defer></script>
```

so:

This worked in **Laravel** *(It was a Blade file that may have automatically resolved the js/app.js URL)*

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

with

```
Route::view('/{path?}', 'app')
    ->where('path', '.*')
    ->name('react');
```

But, I had to do this in **Lumen** *(Not a Blade file)*:

```
<script src="/js/app.js" defer></script>
```

with

```
$router->get('/{all:.*}', function() {
    return view('app');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

## Laravel 8 / redirect only under subdirectory

I wanted to redirect not all non-existing URLs, but only the ones in a specific subdirectory (like https://example.com/subdir/*)

If I just had wanted to **redirect all missing URLs** I could have just used the [fallback route](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#fallback-routes) at the end of the web.php file:

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    //
});
```

But as I wanted to **redirect only urls in subdirectories**, I used this code, which worked for me (just redirecting to /):

```
Route::get('subdirectory/{any}', function($page){return redirect()->to('/');})->where('any', '.*');
```

I found this in the [FallbackRouteTest.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/tests/Integration/Routing/FallbackRouteTest.php#L56).

Comment: It only works for get requests though.

Comment: @steve moretz, you can of course just use ::any for all methods or any specific method you want to redirect. But that is probably rarely useful.

Comment: No I mean the fallback method only works for get requests, but yeah my use cases are always stupidly rare, lol

Answer (score 4):

Add this in the end of routes file

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return View::make('notfound');
});
```

from http://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-and-easy-laravel-routing

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the solution William. However methods 1 & 2 aren't working anymore Laravel 4, and in order to use solution #3 in Laravel 4 you will have to fire the 404 event in your start/global.php file.

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    // i.o. -> this is our catchall!
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297278/laravel-using-any-wildcard-for-all-routes
    Event::fire('404');

    return View::make('error')->with('exception', $exception)->with('code', $code);

    Log::error($exception);
});
```

Now we can handle this in our routes.php file:

```
Event::listen('404', function() {
    // url?
    $url = Request::path();

    // LOGIC HERE

    // else
    return View::make('error');
});
```

Comment: Actually, check this out http://four.laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-404-errors.  You don't have to fire that 404 event yourself, you can just add a listener with App::missing()

Answer (score 1):

Having basic lumen scaffolding. In my case, I have 2 frontend apps and api routes

```
<?php // routes/web.php
/** @var \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router $router */

$router->group([
    'prefix' => '/api/v1',
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'
], function () use ($router) {

    require 'routes-group1.php';
    require 'routes-group2.php';
    // ...
});

$router->get('/admin{any:.*}', function () {
    return file_get_contents('../public/a/index.html');
});

$router->get('{any:.*}', function () {
    return file_get_contents('../public/m/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Fallback Routes Since Laravel 5.5**

Using the `Route::fallback` method, you may define a route that will be executed when no other route matches the incoming request. Typically, unhandled requests will automatically render a "404" page via your application's exception handler. However, since you would typically define the `fallback` route within your `routes/web.php` file, all middleware in the `web` middleware group will apply to the route. You are free to add additional middleware to this route as needed:

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    //
});
```

*Note: The fallback route should always be the last route registered by your application.*