# Send all segments of Laravel route to function

Tags: php, laravel

I want to be able to respond to a route in Larvel 3 that contains an unknown number of segments N.
e.g.

```
/segment_1/...segment_N-1/segment_N
```

The route should send the value of each segment to an anonymous function.

I have tried using:

```
Route::get('/(:any)/(:all?)', function($segments){
    //do something
});
```

This accepts all routes, but only sends the first segment to the function

Is there a simple way in Laravel to achieve what I need?

Comment: I think that you can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297278/laravel-using-any-wildcard-for-all-routes I won't copy others answers and paste theme here.. :)

Comment: thanks - have just found that one myself :-) - trying it out now.

Comment: ok, hope you'll find a solution (you can post it here so others will know in the future)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the best way to do this, but it works for me.

```
 Route::get('(:all)?', function() {
    $current = URI::current();
    $segments = explode ('/', $current);
    foreach ($segments as $key => $value) {
        echo "URI Segment[" . $key . "]" . $value . "<br>";
    }
 });
```