# Get all routes, Laravel 4

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4

What I want is just to use one controller at the moment which should handle every request that comes to my laravel 4 application. The problem is that none of the solutions on stackoverflow or elsewhere are working for me.

That's what i currently have:

```
Route::any('(.*)', function(){
  return View::make('hello');
});
```

Now when browsing to the page I get an error everytime saying:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

Hope somebody could help me out!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Regular expressions are set as requirements and not directly in the route.

```
Route::any('{all}', function($uri)
{
    return View::make('hello');
})->where('all', '.*');
```

Comment: Thx. How to use for example "TestController" here instead of directly returning a view?

Comment: Same deal, but instead of using a closure as the second parameter you'd do `Route::any ('{all}', 'TestController@method');`

Comment: It doesn't need to by `any`, it can be `get`, `post` or another HTTP verb too (etc: if you want to catch all `get` and not any other verb).

Comment: This only works for a single segment it appears. If I go to site.com/asdadasd it's fine, but site.com/asdadasd/adadssa doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: This [post](http://docker.lhsm.com.br/304224e3-4802-41bd-bed7-d68927f5cb5a) can help understand this solution too

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => '/', 'before' => 'MAKEYOUROWNFILTER'), function()
{

    // your routers after the / ....
});
```

// and in filters.php

```
Route::filter('MAKEYOUROWNFILTER', function()
{

    // do stuff or just
    return View::make('hello');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on #Jason Lewis's answer to redirect to the root page:

```
Route::any('{all}', function($uri)
{
    return Redirect::to('/');
})->where('all', '.*');
```