# Laravel 4 routing with :all wildcard

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes

In laravel 3 I was able to route with `:all` wildcard like this:

```
Route::get('test/(:all)', array();
```

so I could pass all segments after *test* in one variable eg. from link like

http://mytestsite.dev/test/it/is/working

I would have *it/is/working* string passed to a controller.

How to do it in laravel 4, regarding that there is no `:all` wildcard?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13297541/1799322

Comment: This specific answer is what you want http://stackoverflow.com/a/16181707/1317935

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all routes, Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178426/get-all-routes-laravel-4)

Comment: Answers to those questions are not directly solving my problem, but I found there what I was looking for. Thanks guys :)