# Laravel routing group for muliple domains with wildcards, how to handle domain suffixes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have 3 domains which, on my local server, take the format:

- mydomainfirst.local
- mydomainsecond.local
- mydomainthird.local

In my routes.php file, I have the following:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{domain}.{suffix}'), function() {

    Route::get('/', 'Primary@initialize');

});
```

The idea is to take the `$domain` variable in my controller and extract the first/second/third part from it, which works fine. However, now my site is online, this routing file no longer works and throws a Http-not-found exception. After a while, I have figured that the problem is that the domains have now taken the format `mydomainfirst.co.uk`. Because there are now 2 parts to the domain suffix, it seems I need to do this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{domain}.{a}.{b}'), function() {

    Route::get('/', 'Primary@initialize');

});
```

To get it to work. Which is stupid. How can I tell it to just accept any suffix? Is there an 'anything' wildcard I can use?

I have tried a few things like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16181707/521392) but it doesn't work with route groups.

**EDIT:** It seems the [Enhanced Router](https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router) package would at least enable me to add a `where` clause to the route group, but does it solve the problem of how to set a wildcard that will match an indeterminate number of segments? I need something like:

```
{domain}.{anything}
```

That will match both:

mydomainfirst.**local** *AND* mydomainfirst.**co**.**uk**

?

Comment: Looks like [this package](https://github.com/jasonlewis/enhanced-router) could help with your issue

Comment: Can you try if `->where('anything', '.*')` works?

Comment: I can't even install this package, unfortunately. Looks like it is incompatible with the latest Laravel routing? Screenshot: http://tinyurl.com/qdllvuo

Comment: Yes it has some open issues on github and it seems it's not compatible with Laravel 4.2. You could try [this fork](https://github.com/hamedb89/enhanced-router)

Comment: @lukasgeiter Thanks, but I now I can't get this package to install! Exactly as per instructions, I have added the respositories block to composer.json, updated providers array, ran composer update, and then dump-autoload. But I just get *Class 'Hamedbahrami\EnhancedRouter\EnhancedRouterServiceProvider' not found*?

Comment: I'm gonna try some things myself and come back to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok let me first say that the code of [this package](https://github.com/hamedb89/enhanced-router) actually looks good and should work. Even if you can't get it running by installing you could take the files and use the code with your own service provider etc.

But there's also a kind of quick and dirty solution. (Actually the package does it pretty similar, but it looks a lot nicer ;))

First, here's how you can do it for one route:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{domain}.{tld}'), function(){
    Route::get('/', 'Primary@initialize')->where('tld', '.*');
});
```

So the where condition for the route group actually gets set on the individual route.

Of course you don't want to do this for every route inside that group so you can use a simple foreach loop:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{domain}.{tld}'), function($group){

    Route::get('/', 'Primary@initialize');

    foreach($group->getRoutes() as $route){
        $route->where('tld', '.*');
    }
});
```

**Note:** The loop *needs* to come after all routes. Otherwise they won't registered and therefore not returned with `getRoutes()`

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant and works like a charm. Many thanks!