# Redirecting all requests for assets to equivalent folder on different domain

Tags: redirect, laravel

I have 3 sites all running on the same Laravel installation. One site is the 'master' site, and I want to keep all my assets; css, scripts files, etc in its relevant child directories.
So my directory structure looks like this:

```
-Root - site1 - css
              - scripts
              - images
      - site2
      - site3
```

with my sites' URLs:

```
www.mysite1.com
www.mysite2.com
www.mysite3.com
```

It would be much more convenient to keep all my assets for all 3 sites in the same place, therefore I would prefer not to have to make new css/scripts/ folders in the other 2 sites' folders. At the moment, I am using `View::share` to share the root domain for site1 accross all views for all sites so I can then use it in my paths; for example:

```
<img src="{{ $rootDomain . 'images/someimage.jpg' }}">
```

But I am now thinking this is stupid... it would be much easier if I could set up some intelligent redirect system...

What is the best way to achieve this? Can/should I do this in Laravel's routes.php file? Or Htaccess? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly advice against redirecting assets. Think about that way. Every time someone visits site2 or site3 (the non-master sites) The browser makes multiple requests to the current application to download the assets. All these requests would return a redirect and cause the browser to do **each request twice**. So the number of requests (for assets) is multiplied by factor 2. And that's not good since you should keep requests at a minimum.

I honestly think you have already found the best way to do it by just using the domain of the master site for all your assets on the other sites.

If you want to make it a *bit* prettier, you could write a helper function.

```
function master_asset(path){
    // get rootDomain from config or something like that.
    return $rootDomain . $path;
}
```

And use it in a similar fashion as `asset()`

```
<img src="{{ master_asset('images/someimage.jpg') }}">
```

Comment: My problem is that the sites actually share many of the same view templates, so I want to make sure the syntax for linking assets can always be the same regardless of which site I am working with. This is quite a good solution, because I guess I can use this same code for all 3 sites' view templates. (Annoyingly I have to now go through them and change everything though). Do you think doing it this way would be better than doing it with .htaccess?

Comment: You mean redirecting with `.htaccess`? That's still the same problem. Twice the requests. It would be slightly better than using a route because Laravel don't has to start up but still I'd prefer linking the assets to the right URL in the first place. And can't you just search and replace `asset(` with `master_asset(` in your views?

Comment: OK, yes- everything you're saying makes sense. And yes, search & replace will probably do the job. I guess I'm slightly reluctant because it means I have to hard-code the master domain URL, which somewhat undoes some of the elegancy I already have. (Remember [yesterday's question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27680353/521392) which you also kindly helped me with!)

Comment: But with any other method you would have a hardcoded master domain to make the redirect?! Also I wouldn't call it hardcoded if it's in a config file and easily changeable...

Comment: Well, not quite- at present I can just 'hard-code' `mysite1` and leave out the domain suffix, which means there is no change required when migrating from my local server to online. But, yeah, no big deal to change one line in a config file I guess.

Comment: Or make use of [Environment Configuration](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration) and you don't have to change anything on deploy ;)

Comment: Gotcha. Points go to you. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to do this, would be to just specify the full url when including assets. That's the standard way of doing it.