# Laravel 4: Create a default route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a default route in my Laravel 4 REST API, that hits, when none of my other defined routes matches the request, to return a specific error to the caller.

Is this possible? Unfortunately, I found nothing in the docs, so I played around and tried using a wildcard (`*`) as the last Route definition in my `routes.php` but that doesn't work.

```
Route::when("*", function(){
    throw new CustomizedException('Route not found...');
});
```

When I have this route and do an `artisan routes`, I get an Exception:
`{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Object of class Closure could not be converted to string","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/CampaigningTools\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/Console\/RoutesCommand.php","line":153}}`

Calling an inexistent route does not trigger my customized Exception, but the standard one:
`{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException","message":"","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/CampaigningTools\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Routing\/Router.php","line":1429}}`

I also tried using `any` as suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13297541/320564), but that also doesn't work:

```
Route::any( '(.*)', function( $page ){
    throw new ValidationException('Custom error');
});
```

This route also doesn't fire, when I call an inexistent route.

Any hints, what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there is no matching route, Laravel throws a "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException". You can simply write your own error handler to catch that exception and do something else (have a look at http://laravel.com/docs/errors).

Add one of the following two blocks (e.g. in your "app/start/global.php" in the "Application Error Handler" block):

```
App::error(function(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException $exception, $code)
{
    // do something
});
```

Or:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 19):

Took me a while to figure this out, actually @devo was very close:

```
Route::get('{slug}', function($slug) {

    // check your DB for $slug, get the page, etc...

})->where('slug', '^.*');
```

This will catch the / too. If you'd rather handle the home page separately change the regexp to: where('slug', '^.+');

Comment: I was going to write the same answer ... +1 for saving my time :D

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
Route::get('{slug}', function($slug) {
    // get the page from database using Page model
    $page = Page::where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();

    if ( is_null($page) ) {
        return App::abort(404);
    }

    return View::make('page')->with('page',$page);
});

// Show 404 Page

App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

Comment: this works only for simple urls like /foo. If you have /foo/bar it will not catch it...

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this at the end of your route file?

```
Route::any( '/{default?}', function( $page ){
    throw new ValidationException('Custom error');
});
```

Or

```
Route::any('/{default?}', 'TestController@yourMethod'); // pointing to a method displaying a 404 custom page
```