# How can I check whether the route "URL" exists?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

In *Laravel 5.2*, is there a particular way (handler) to check whether a route is existing or not? Let's say, for a basic URL like:

```
http://www.example.com/laravel
```

I then want to handle the non-existing URLs (like: `/laravel`) from my Main Page Router, which is:

```
Route::get('/{page}', funtion(){
    //check if $page is a valid route URL? Or 404?
});
```

How do I purposely check whether this route is a valid one or not?

Comment: hopw about Route::has('route.name');

Comment: Do you mean `Route::has('route.laravel')` according to example route above?

Comment: Do you mean: 1) check if the route alias has been used; or 2) check if a given URL will match one of your routes?

Comment: @tbuteler >> Actually, i want to handle routes from main page route `Route::get('/{page}')`. If there's no route, i wanna handle something from main page. So i suppose it is `no (2)` from your question just now.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942646/laravel-4-create-a-default-route

Comment: Sorry all. I edited my question a bit :) Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following as my last route:

```
Route::any('{catchall}', function($page) {
    abort(404);
} )->where('catchall', '(.*)');
```

If you are not aware yet, `abort(404)` will return the view `404.blade.php` from `resources/views/errors`.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put your `Route::get('/{page}','MainController@getPage');` last. That way if it finds another route before it will use it but if it doesn't then it will get caught by this. For example:

```
Route::get('/welcome','WelcomeController@getWelcome');
Route::get('/test','TestController@getTest');
Route::get('/{page}','MainController@getPage');
```

If you were to hit `/welcome` or `/test` it should route them to the correct controller. If you where to hit `/hello` it should go to the `MainController` and hit function `getPage($page)` with `$page` being the page you hit.

If it hits `MainController@getPage` you know it was basically a 404.

If you need to know before you hit the route for some reason you could create something like this:

```
Route::get('/checkurl/{page}',function($page) {
    $exists = Route::has('/' . $page);
    return (new Response(json_encode(['exists'=>$exists]),200);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding last route with any catch doesn't works anymore with laravel 5.5.1+