# Laravel + AngularJS Nginx routing

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, nginx, laravel-5.3

I have the following issue,
I need to configure Nginx, so on any URL user accesses, it will keep the uri (example `domain.com/some/url/`), but pass to laravel only `/` and let Angular handle the routing.

```
Route::get('/', function(){
   return view('index');
});
```

And when accessing `/api/{anything}` Laravel will kick in.

For now I return `index.html` from public folder until I find solution
Here is My Config:

```
location / {
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
location /api {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

I know I can make a route like:

```
Route::get('{anything?}', function(){
    return view('index');
});
```

But is to broad.

Update:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ / break;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
location /api {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for NGINX to execute the index.blade.php script on all requests? If so you need fastcgi configured.

Comment: I have fastcgi, the question is not about how to process php files, but about how to return always `/` route from laravel but keep `URI` for angular

Comment: You can strip the URL with a simple rewrite rule: `rewrite ^/(.*)$ / last;`

Comment: @FaisalMemon where should I put it? I tried and had redirect cycle.

Comment: Sorry, change 'last' to 'break'. It should go in the location where you want it to execute.

Comment: @FaisalMemon no, still Laravel gets route

Comment: Can you post updatedconfig?

Comment: @FaisalMemon Updated

Comment: From the above config, a request to any location other than /api should result in the request file or index.php being returned to the user. I don't see how the request is getting to Laravel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't achieve you goal with simple rewrite. Laravel always knows about the real `URI`.

The key point is that you need to handle all requests with just one route. Laravel uses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable to route and it is passed to Laravel from `fastcgi`. The variable `REQUEST_URI` is set in `fastcgi_params` file from nginx's `$request_uri` variable:

```
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
```

So you need to pass `REQUEST_URI` as `/` to Laravel to handle request `/bla/bla` as it is `/`.

Just add one line to your config:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    # now you have smth like this
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;

    # add the following line right after fastcgi_params to rewrite value of the variable
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI       /;
}
```

If you have `/api/` as well, you need some edits for the line:

```
set $request_url $request_uri;
if ($request_uri !~ ^/api/(.*)$ ) {
    set $request_url /;
}
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI $request_url;
```

Nginx warns that `if` is an evil, that's just a first idea.

To sum up:

`/` goes to Laravel `/` route.

`/api/*` go to Laravel api routes.

Another requests go to Laravel `/` route.

Comment: Nice, but this also breaks my `api routes`. They all have prefix `/api/`

Comment: So you have `/` for angular and `/api/(.*)` for api. Ok, check the update.

Comment: Thank you works, but what you think is better this solution or just create a laravel route with any url?

Comment: I prefer Laravel routes. You can read about it here (answer for laravel5) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297278/laravel-using-any-wildcard-for-all-routes 

P.S. There is a dirty workaround - without changing `nginx` remove Laravel route for `/` and place your view to `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`. So `api` calls will go to `api`, any other request will go to this view. It just gives 404 error header :)