# React router nested router aren't working

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-router

I'm making a website with **laravel** backend and react as a front-end library and using React-Router &
I've this code

```
<Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={ProductsPage}/>
          <Route path="/category/:id" component={CategoryPage}/>
</Switch>
```

which I also tried switching to

```
<Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={ProductsPage}/>
          <Route path="/category">
              <Route path="/:id" component={CategoryPage} />
          </Route>
```

here's my **web.php** page

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
Route::view('/{path?}', 'app');
```

Everything works normally except nested routes if I visit /category/805 it gives me a 404

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297278/laravel-using-any-wildcard-for-all-routes

Comment: try using ```exact path``` for all routes, including nested ones.