# Laravel: capture everything after '/' in a route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have a route that looks like this:

```
Route::namespace('Api\HelpGuides')->prefix('help')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{userInput}', 'FetchArticlesController')
    ->where('userInput', '.*');
});
```

And the controller that looks like this:

```
    public function __invoke(Request $request, string $userInput) ...
```

I want to be able to capture the $userInput so if I receive a request from the front-end that is like:

```
/api/help/anything/could/be/in/here?including=params
```

That I can consume in the FetchArticlesController.

When I dump out $userInput in my controller, I am given everything up to the query string, so in the above example, it dumps out

```
/anything/could/be/in/here
```

Is there a way I can make it dump out everything after my defined route? e.g. ANYTHING after `/api/help/` ? I would ideally like that $userInput string to look like:

```
/anything/could/be/in/here?including=params
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Using (:any?) wildcard for ALL routes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297278/laravel-using-any-wildcard-for-all-routes)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture anything:

```php
Route::pattern('anything', '.*');

Route::namespace('Api\HelpGuides')->prefix('help')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{anything}', 'FetchArticlesController');
});
```

The `$anything` argument in your controller method will be... anything, including `/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get query string with `$request->getQueryString()`.

So you can do

```
Route::namespace('Api\HelpGuides')->prefix('help')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{userInput}', 'FetchArticlesController')->where('userInput', '.*');
});
```

```
public function __invoke(Request $request, string $userInput)
{
    $userInput = trim("{$userInput}?{$request->getQueryString()}", '?');
}
```

I trim question mark if it there is no query string on the end.

Answer (score 1):

try $request->fullUrl() or $request->getRequestUri()